# Edit files in directory using a buildTool plugin in Swift

Tags: swift, plugins, swift-package-manager, build-tools

I've been searching and trying to build a `buildTool()` SPM plugin which takes all files on a folder and edit them on the go before the build actually happens and then end the build. The aim is to add a line of code in each file without creating any new output file, but keeping the original one edited. I haven't found a way to do what I'm describing, is there any way to do this or it is a limitation for `buildTool()` plugins to edit files instead of generating new ones?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't make a comment yet, I don't have enough "rank". I Have been trying to find something or even create it myself. The reason why we haven't found one is because it is not currently possible to do. Any Swift Package Plugin that runs as a build tool is strictly prohibited from modifying any of the code within the project directory. However a Command Plugin is allowed to save and edit files. I would recommend trying to search for a Command tool. It is a little different and you will need to do a little extra work to get it to run at build time if that is what you want.